# How to use plural names for nested resources?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I am using Ruby on Rails v3.2.2 and I would like to use plural names for nested resources. That is, in my `config/routes.rb` I have (note: "category" and "article" are sample resources):

```
resources :categories do
  resources :articles do
    collection do
      get  'one'
      post 'two'
      put  'three'
    end
    member do
      get  'four'
      post 'five'
      put  'six'
    end
  end
end
```

The above statements generates the following:

```
$ rake routes
  one_category_articles GET    /categories/:category_id/articles/one(.:format)      articles#one
  two_category_articles POST   /categories/:category_id/articles/two(.:format)      articles#two
three_category_articles PUT    /categories/:category_id/articles/three(.:format)    articles#three
  four_category_article GET    /categories/:category_id/articles/:id/four(.:format) articles#four
  five_category_article POST   /categories/:category_id/articles/:id/five(.:format) articles#five
   six_category_article PUT    /categories/:category_id/articles/:id/six(.:format)  articles#six
      category_articles GET    /categories/:category_id/articles(.:format)          articles#index
                        POST   /categories/:category_id/articles(.:format)          articles#create
   new_category_article GET    /categories/:category_id/articles/new(.:format)      articles#new
  edit_category_article GET    /categories/:category_id/articles/:id/edit(.:format) articles#edit
       category_article GET    /categories/:category_id/articles/:id(.:format)      articles#show
                        PUT    /categories/:category_id/articles/:id(.:format)      articles#update
                        DELETE /categories/:category_id/articles/:id(.:format)      articles#destroy
             categories GET    /categories(.:format)                                categories#index
                        POST   /categories(.:format)                                categories#create
           new_category GET    /categories/new(.:format)                            categories#new
          edit_category GET    /categories/:id/edit(.:format)                       categories#edit
               category GET    /categories/:id(.:format)                            categories#show
                        PUT    /categories/:id(.:format)                            categories#update
                        DELETE /categories/:id(.:format)                            categories#destroy
```

I would like to change statements in my `config/routes.rb` so to generate following routers with *plural* names *only* for the *`category_article`* "part" (that is, I would like to use `categories_article`/`categories_articles` respectively instead of `category_article`/`category_articles`):

```
$ rake routes
# Note: I marked changes from the previous outputting with '=>'.
=>   one_categories_articles GET    /categories/:category_id/articles/one(.:format)      articles#one
=>   two_categories_articles POST   /categories/:category_id/articles/two(.:format)      articles#two
=> three_categories_articles PUT    /categories/:category_id/articles/three(.:format)    articles#three
=>   four_categories_article GET    /categories/:category_id/articles/:id/four(.:format) articles#four
=>   five_categories_article POST   /categories/:category_id/articles/:id/five(.:format) articles#five
=>    six_categories_article PUT    /categories/:category_id/articles/:id/six(.:format)  articles#six
=>       categories_articles GET    /categories/:category_id/articles(.:format)          articles#index
                             POST   /categories/:category_id/articles(.:format)          articles#create
        new_category_article GET    /categories/:category_id/articles/new(.:format)      articles#new
       edit_category_article GET    /categories/:category_id/articles/:id/edit(.:format) articles#edit
            category_article GET    /categories/:category_id/articles/:id(.:format)      articles#show
                             PUT    /categories/:category_id/articles/:id(.:format)      articles#update
                             DELETE /categories/:category_id/articles/:id(.:format)      articles#destroy
                  categories GET    /categories(.:format)                                categories#index
                             POST   /categories(.:format)                                categories#create
                new_category GET    /categories/new(.:format)                            categories#new
               edit_category GET    /categories/:id/edit(.:format)                       categories#edit
                    category GET    /categories/:id(.:format)                            categories#show
                             PUT    /categories/:id(.:format)                            categories#update
                             DELETE /categories/:id(.:format)
```

Comment: Did you think twice? `category_articles` shows without a doubt that for the respective helper you need to provide a category and no articles. With `categories_articles` you'll be confused.

Comment: `resources :categories, :as => 'categories' do`

Comment: @DanS - Your code doesn't work as expected.

Comment: @jdoe - I would like to use that approach because I would like to successfully use, for example, the `polymorphic_path` method. At this time I get a `NoMethodError` error if I use `polymorphic_path(Categories::Article)` since it returns `categories_articles_path` (and not `category_articles_path`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you aren't satisfied with the provided helpers then you can use the magic:

```
<%= link_to 'One', [:one, @category, Article] %>
# /categories/123/articles/one

<%= link_to 'Four', [:four, @category, @article] %>
# /categories/123/articles/456/four

<%= link_to 'Edit the article', [:edit, @category, @article] %>
# /categories/123/articles/456/edit

<%= link_to 'All articles for the category', [@category, Article] %>
# /categories/123/articles
```

The very same approach can be used to specify the `:url` option for the `form_for` helper.

I hope you got the idea!

P.S. Note the using of a class (like `Article`) to specify that you want to see all records and using of a model instance (like `@article`) to say that you are about to see one article.